# how to change state of a Switch programmatically [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

I've to Switches A & B. I want whenever would I tap on switch A, it will change the state of B and vice versa.
How to do that in Android studio?

Here's my code of Switches

```
    //first switch
        flw_Rate_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

}...


//2nd switch
        lqd_followed_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {


}...
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define your switches:

```
Switch a; // define your switch
Switch b;
```

Switches can switches them selves on or off on click, so we need to tell them to switch the other:

```
a.setOnClickListener(
     new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
               b.setChecked(!b.isChecked);
         }
      });
b.setOnClickListener(
     new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
               a.setChecked(!a.isChecked);
         }
      });
```

In onClick method, we tell the switch if user clicked on it, set the other switch check status reverse, in other word, we tell them if the other is off, turn it on, and if it's on, turn it of. The **setChecked** method doing this. And the argument, says reverse the switch status.

Comment: It isn't working. Also I'm using SwitchCompat in android studio and its override method is @onCheckedChanged

Comment: @tayyaba debian Can you post your entire code in you activity?

Comment: @tayyaba debian  Thank you but i need to see whole codes in you activity to help better, Can you post it?

Comment: Can't add too much code. you please elaborate your answer with just by an example. It would be great help.

Comment: I don't know what you done in your code, the problem can be every thing, unless you get an error. so if you get an error please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

### File-activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hina.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/container" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/on1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="ON" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/on2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/testbutton"
                android:text="OFF"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/LstPeriodOptions"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/container" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### File-MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hina.myapplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.example.hina.myapplication.R.id.on2;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button on1;
    Button off1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         on1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.on1);
         off1= (Button) findViewById(on2);
        on1.setOnClickListener(this);
        off1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (on1.isPressed()){
            on1.setEnabled(false);
            off1.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (off1.isPressed()){
            off1.setEnabled(false);
            on1.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your answer.